# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error with Hangfire

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, hangfire

I had this error before (without Hangfire) and at that time I solved it with adding this line before the `WebRequest`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

But now I'm calling a WebRequest with Hangfire, that queues up a BackgroundJob and get this error.

I've tried to add the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` in the Startup.cs of the Hangfire.

I also tried to put it right before the `WebRequest`, to no avail.

Also tried all sorts of variants of the SecurityProtocol, such as:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But it still poops the error.

Comment: I think we might have a similar problem with Http requests made inside Hangfire jobs not picking the correct security protocol despite us setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` appropriately. Did you solve this yet?